# WPF Hide top Panel Layout

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF and I'm having trouble understanding all the panels and grids and how they work together to build the desired layout. I am trying to build a window where the top section (panel) has a bunch of controls and the panel has a hide button. When the user clicks on "hide" the top portion slides up and the bottom portion expands to take its place. What combination of panels can I use to produce this type of layout? Is there an example of this somewhere that I haven't found yet?

[image: Sample Layout]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi If you want to solve this problem using MVVM try this

> xaml. Here I have a grid that has three rows.

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding GridVisibility}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock Text="here will be some controls" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding ShowHidecommand}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

> xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        SetInitialState();
    }
    void SetInitialState()
    {
        buttonState = ButtonState.Shown;
        GridVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ButtonText = "Hide";
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string buttonText;
    public  string ButtonText
    {
        get
        {
            return buttonText;
        }
        set
        {
            buttonText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ButtonText");
        }
    }

    private Visibility gridVisibility;
    public  Visibility GridVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return gridVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            gridVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GridVisibility");
        }
    }

    private MyCommand showHideCommand;
    public MyCommand ShowHidecommand
    {
        get { return showHideCommand ?? (showHideCommand = new MyCommand((o) => OnShowHideCommand(o), () => true)); }
    }

    public void OnShowHideCommand(object obj)
    {
        if (buttonState == ButtonState.Shown)
        {
            buttonState = ButtonState.Hidden;
            GridVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ButtonText = "Show";
        }
        else
        {
            buttonState = ButtonState.Shown;
            GridVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ButtonText = "Hide";
        }

    }

    ButtonState buttonState;
    enum ButtonState
    { 
        Shown,
        Hidden
    }
}
```

> MyCommand.cs

```
    public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    Action<object> executeAction;
    Func<bool> canExecute;

    public MyCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        this.executeAction = executeAction;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (canExecute != null)
            return canExecute();
        else
            return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (executeAction != null)
            executeAction(parameter);
    }
}
```

Here what we are doing is we have binded the Visibility of Grid which needs to be visible or collapsed on the bassis of Button state. Next we binded the Content of button to set its text according to button state.and finally we have binded the the Command of Button which will switch the Visibility and Button Content. Key here is the * height of last Grid Row so that it will move up to cover the area that is been collapsed. I hope i make any sense

> Output
>   [image: Hide]

[image: Show]

> Alternatively if you want to solve it using code behind then just subscribe to click event and set visibility of grid

```
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="showHideGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="here will be some controls" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Show" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

> Click event

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            if (button.Content == "Show")
            {
                button.Content = "Hide";
                showHideGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                button.Content = "Show";
                showHideGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @ethicallogics, it works perfectly. If I could accept the answer twice, I would!

Comment: Thanks for covering both methods :)